# Multiple passwords for same site in Opera

Tags: browser, opera

I am using the latest version of Opera and I need it to save more than one password for the same site like other browser do.

Comment: Don't use a browser's built in password management, that's very insecure. Use a password manager.

Comment: @Raystafarian: as a blanket statement, that's very inaccurate. I'm perfectly happy that my passwords are as secure in Opera as in my system in general. To view my passwords, Opera asks me to enter my system password, i.e. someone would either need access to my system locally and know my password, or hack through my firewall etc. (in which case any password manager wouldn't offer an additional challenge to the hacker). In fact, Chrome deliberately does not use a master password to avoid giving a "false sense of security" (Opera uses the same model).

Answer (score 1):

You can save as many passwords as you’d like for the same website.

Go ahead and type in your username and password and login. Then confirm that you want to save them in the drop-down toolbar. To choose between stored passwords, type in the first character of the username in the username field and Opera will fill in the rest.

As you may have understood by now, the only requirement is that you cannot save multiple passwords for the same username for the same domain.